# Using Plink to change configs on multiple cisco switches

Tags: powershell, cisco

I have a PS script right now that lets me log into a range of switches one after another.

```
70..80 | % { plink "172.16.15.$_" -l enterusername -pw enterpassword}
```

This allows me to start at switch ending in .70 and once I am done and type exit, it automatically logs into the next one in sequence.

I want to create a text file that contains the changes I want to make to the running-config on the switch, such as maybe adding a user to 100 or so switches. How can I add to the PS script to make it so that it applies the changes to the config contained in the created text file? I am trying to automate changes to 100 edge switches vs having to type the config into each switch.

Or instead of pointing to a text file, can I somehow add the changes for the switch config right into the PS script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.53b/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) (emphasis mine):

> ## 7.2 Using Plink
>
> This section describes the basics of how to use Plink for interactive logins and for automated processes.
>
> Once you've got a console window to type into, you can just type plink on its own to bring up a usage message. This tells you the version of Plink you're using, and gives you a brief summary of how to use Plink:
>
> ```
> Z:\sysosd>plink
> PuTTY Link: command-line connection utility
> Release 0.53
> Usage: plink [options] [user@]host [command]
>        ("host" can also be a PuTTY saved session name)
> Options:
>   -v        show verbose messages
>   -load sessname  Load settings from saved session
>   -ssh -telnet -rlogin -raw
>             force use of a particular protocol (default SSH)
>   -P port   connect to specified port
>   -l user   connect with specified username
>   -m file   read remote command(s) from file
>   -batch    disable all interactive prompts
> ```

So all you need to do is create your command file, and add it to the commandline:

```
70..80 | ForEach-Object {
    plink "172.16.15.$_" -l enterusername -pw enterpassword -m 'C:\commands.txt'
}
```

Comment: So I do this now, it doesn't seem to apply the changes. I saved the file both as a txt and as a bat, and got the same result. My script for the switch is a basic one, just adding a new vlan. I have it set up as en, conf t, vlan 4, end, exit and each line separated with a "!". Any idea why plink is not pushing through the config change? Our switches have a log in banner and all I am seeing is the banner on plink, that's it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Cisco switches, so I can't help you there.